# How to configure git encoding for German Umlaute on Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: git, encoding, character-encoding, diacritics, multiplatform

I noticed that commit messages that contain *German Umlaute* are not displayed correctly when I run `git log` in *Git Bash* on Windows. Those commits were made on Ubuntu using the *Terminal*. Normally, commit messages are written in English but when it comes to names there is no way around, e.g. `Added library by Simon Jünker.` I guess it can also be *Git Bash* which cannot handle the character encoding. But maybe there is a setting to force `utf-8` encoding for writing and displaying text in any module (*Git Gui*, *Git k*) of Git.

What is your multi-platform character encoding setup for Git? Please, make sure to include the configuration for both platforms in your answer. You can also add MacOS.

Comment: *there is no way around* is only half-correct: Simon would surely also be happy if his name was written *Simon Juenker*...

Comment: Maybe you found somewhere a answer for your question? Could you provide it here please?

Comment: @eckes, my name is Benoît and I won't be happy if you would write it "Benoist" because it is so old-fashioned ! Remembrance of the dark ages before the invention of ^

Answer (score 4):

[This link](https://makandracards.com/makandra/29621-how-to-fix-git-diff-does-not-show-umlauts-or-other-non-ascii-characters-properly) showed the way to solve this issue:

Please try:

```
set LESSCHARSET=UTF-8
```

in the Windows command Shell (cmd.exe) and run the git commands again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set git config on GIT Bash prompt with one of the following commands:

```
git config --global i18n.commitEncoding utf8
git config --global i18n.commitEncoding cp1252
```

If somone in your team uses another encoding, you will have a missmatch.
Petra uses utf8:

```
git commit -m "Petras message with umlaut ÄäÜüÖöß etc."
```

Karl uses cp1252:

```
git commit -m "Karls message with umlaut ÄäÜüÖöß etc."
```

Sara checks out the pushed branch and depending on her encoding she will see one of the messages wellformed and the other missformed.

```
git config --global i18n.commitEncoding utf8
git log -n 2 --oneline
    Petras message with umlaut ÄäÜüÖöß etc.
    Karls message with umlaut <C4><E4><D6><F6><DC><FC><DF> etc.

git config --global i18n.commitEncoding cp1252
git log -n 2 --oneline
    Petras message with umlaut Ã„Ã¤ÃœÃ¼Ã–Ã¶ÃŸ etc.
    Karls message with umlaut ÄäÜüÖöß etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X things should work fine with the built-in terminal as long as you have the encoding set in Preferences > Settings > Advanced and you’ve selected “Set locale environment variables on startup.” (These are the defaults.)

Apparently MSysGit on Windows doesn’t support UTF-8, but if you pipe git command output through a copy of `less` from cygwin things will work. There’s some useful info [in the msysgit Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/e7887444ec8f4cf5/14ad6d31d4fa8c0e?#14ad6d31d4fa8c0e).

Comment: The question not about Mac.